# round to the nearest multiple of 10 when update the table prices

Tags: php, laravel

how can i add round to the nearest multiple of 10 to request I already have:
`Clothes::query()->update ([ 'price_kiev_1' => \DB::raw("price_kiev_1 + price_kiev_1 / 100 * $value") ]);`

in the request i increase the price by % and I want to round it up in the same request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like :

```
Clothes::query()->update([
    'price_kiev_1' => \DB::raw("ROUND(price_kiev_1 + price_kiev_1 / 100 * $value, -1)")

]);
```

The second parameter of the `ROUND()` function defines the position of the rounding.

```
mysql> SELECT ROUND(1.298, 1);
        -> 1.3
mysql> SELECT ROUND(1.298, 0);
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT ROUND(23.298, -1);
        -> 20
```

Comment: it works, thanks!